# References on philosophical aspects of experimental design

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, scientific-method, empiricism, measurement-theory

I am an engineer working in molecular neuroscience field, hence getting exposure in both solving practical problems (how to image fish brain) and molecular bio questions (do neurons X connect to neurons Y?). Our field spend a lot of time highlighting [reproducibility crisis](https://www.nature.com/news/1-500-scientists-lift-the-lid-on-reproducibility-1.19970) but I don't seem to be able to find references or writing on the following problem of resources allocation:

- funding experiments vs
- funding better experimental design and data shepherding

As I see it today (from the perspective of R1 US institutions) most resources are given to independent professors who then give it to students to work on either novel problems (which leads to waste of time because students are not professionals yet) or well-established problems (which leads to producing a lot of new data about old molecule X that nobody cares about). Some are arguing that [shepherding data is a good investment](https://www.nature.com/articles/473285a), but it is rare.

**Which are the philosophers or theories discuss aspects of [experimental design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments), particularly in regards to value-theoretic or economic considerations?**

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: This is quite a narrow focus. Are you sure there's a subdiscipline that addresses the narrow interpretation? Maybe you can also attack this in [another forum here on SE](https://stackexchange.com/sites#)? Perhaps Data Science? I'm a business analyst, and this seems like it might be an IT management question in terms of ROI?

Comment: Edited to avoid 'off-topic objection'.

Comment: @JD I think that's a good suggestion to look into IT world. In some sense, I am asking about "philosophy of balancing development *versus* design and paying technical debt" or along those lines. We discuss that in IT a lot, but not in science IMHO

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

I'm no specialist, but I'll give it a stab. First, you might be interested in [SEP: Measurement in Science](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/measurement-science/). Some other possible resources that you can follow up with are [SEP: Experiment in Biology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/biology-experiment/), [PhilPapers: Experimental Philosophy of Science](https://philpapers.org/browse/experimental-philosophy-of-science/), and [Blackwell's Companion to the Philosophy of Science](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Blackwell_Guide_to_the_Philosophy_of/Lf_uDyM6gLwC?hl=en&gbpv=0). I have an older edition, but the article *Experiment* by [David C. Gooding](http://gooding.socialpsychology.org/) contains the following references:

[image]